# Void methods cannot return a value error while trying to return something in a forEach method

Tags: java

I have a `snippet` as below

```
private String getString() {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2");
    stringList.forEach(item ->
        {
            if (item.equals("s1"))
                return item;
        });
    return null;
}
```

Now I get a compilation error `Void methods cannot return a value` while I try to `return item`. I googled and couldn't understand why this is happening and the solution to this problem. How do I `return item` in the above `forEach` loop?

Comment: @Tim: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: I don't think this is really an "exact duplicate": it's not asking about setting a variable outside the loop like that other question is.  This problem could be solved by adding variables outside the loop to be modified from within it, but that's a little awkward and not really the best solution.  It's simpler to use something like `stringList.stream().findFirst(...)` instead of `forEach` in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - the answer you've provided does not fit this question. The right answer to this question isn't contained in it.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You already know the String has the value of `"s1"`, so why do you need to use such complicated logic to determine that?

Comment: Note that the `return item` is attempting to return from the lambda expression, not from the `getString()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood lambdas. A lambda is an executable statement that may be executed immediately, or deferred; more importantly, it has its own method signature.

In the following code, you've defined an anonymous method. What is its signature?

```
    stringList.forEach(item ->
    {
        if (item.equals("s1"))
            return item;
    });
```

The answer is that your anonymous method has the following equivalent representation:

```
private void myAnonymousMethod( String item ) {
    if ( item.equals("s1"))
        return item;
}
```

Do you now see your mistake? Your anonymous method has a `void` return type, but you're trying to return a value.

Instead, you could fix this in a variety of ways:

- When you find the value you're looking for, save it in a local variable outside the scope of the lambda. Pro: introduces the smallest amount of change to your code. Con: the foreach loop will continue to execute after it finds its first match.
- Use a different iterator method, such as `findAny` as indicated in Makoto's post.
- Replace the anonymous method entirely with a normal loop.

Comment: The fact that this is a lambda has nothing to do with the actual error, though.  You can write lambdas which don't return a value which would satisfy the requirements of `forEach`.

Comment: @Makoto - it being a lambda is not the mistake; misusing the lambda, by not understanding lambdas is the mistake. I agree, this could be repaired through use of lambdas or not lambdas.

Comment: @antiduh: Right now I'm using #3 in your solution. Its working fine. Just curious about the `lambda`. I like #1 as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Damien-Amen - #1 is likely a bad solution. `forEach` is meant for iterating across all elements, unconditionally. It looks like you're looking for one specific value and then want to stop (this is implied by your desire for a return statement). In which case, feel free to keep using lambdas and iterator methods, but use the right one.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` is a consumption process.  The functions passed to a `forEach` method are expected to have side effects which do *not* directly result in a value being returned, like printing the contents of the list, or doing some side operation.

Basically, any function that is a `Consumer` or method that returns `void` is fair game here.

Since you're *explicitly* looking for a value, you can use [`Stream#findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) instead.

```
// You don't do anything with the result you want anyway,
// so I'm simply printing it out.  You should determine what you need to do
// with the value you get back.

Optional<String> findResult = stringList().stream().findAny(v -> v.equals("s1"));
findResult.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```